# Magento 1.9: Google Payment Gateway module

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm looking for a module for `Magento Google Pay Gateway` method, please help me, I'm stuck. How to get module or from where I can get, or otherwise is it required to used third party payment gateway module ?

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2, This module contains Google Pay:

```
https://marketplace.magento.com/paypal-module-braintree.html
```

But For Magento 1 We Don't have Ready Made module:

You have to Create module by your own : Reference are [Click Here](https://github.com/magento/payment-improvements/issues/12), [Click Here](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/samples/quickstart-rest-api)